# search in array and return the missing number in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want search in array `id` from database the `id` is number,

ex : `$id=array(0,1,3,6,7);`-> data missing because id is deleted or updated
so i want search in array `id` and i can get result for my new id is `2`

another example :

`$id=array(0,1,2,3,6);`->new `id=4`

`$id=array(0,1,2,3,4,6);`->new `id=5`

`$id=array(0,1,2,3,4,5);`->new `id=6`

---

i make this code but it not work

`$arr1 = $this->login->get_user_id(3); 
        $arr2 = range(0,max($arr1)); 
        $missing = array_diff($arr2,$arr1);
            if (empty($missing)) {
                echo max($arr1);
            }else{
                echo min($missing);
            }`

ok sory for all and thanks for answer my question,
so that my code, and data in `$arr1` is `000,001,002...` so i want read from my id in database wich one number is missing, so i can make full all id from numbering, because if just one number is missing when i update the id in another process it's willbuggy for my sistem

Comment: Out of interest. Why? If it's just to fill up previously removed IDs, then I wouldn't bother, there are plenty of available numbers.

Comment: because i need it for my numbering id, i just need a code and algorithm, my id is more than that, i just want to show a simple example, because my bad english, sory if it's out of interest

Comment: @RyanVincent I so understand it is my answer adopted to his enviroment :)

Comment: ok i update the comment sory for your confused

Answer (score 1):

array of all missed ids. If you want the min, take `$missed[0]`

```
$id=array(0,1,3,6,7);
$missed = array_diff(range(0, max($id)), $id);
$new = $missed ? $missed[0] : max($id)+1;
var_dump($missed); // (2,4,5)
```

Comment: how i can show the the missing `2` and take last number+1 if the all data is full